# Sampling using new VideoReader readFrame() function in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, video

In older versions of MATLAB, it was possible to do

```
V = VideoReader(filename);
for i = 1 : 10 : 1000
    sampled = read(V, i);
end
```

to sample frames from a video (in this case every 10th). I also *think* I remember there being a `V.NumberOfFrames` field that actually stored the number of frames in the video.

Since MATLAB 2015a (I believe...it was definitely around this version), they have redone their [`VideoReader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html) class and member functions. Now to get the number of frames, one must do `V.Duration * V.FrameRate`, and sampling is no longer as simple as selecting the frame index in the read call. [`read()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html) is now deprecated and should be replaced by [`readFrame()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.readframe.html). Furthermore, it is now much more difficult (and slower) to sample a video. According to the documentation, one should now read a video as

```
V = VideoReader(filename);
while hasFrame(V)
    frame = readFrame(V);
end
```

For sampling purposes, it appears that one must do one of two things:

1) Insert a modulo if statement, but still read every frame

```
i = 0;
V = VideoReader(filename);
while hasFrame(V)
    readFrame(V);
    if mod(i, samplingRate)
        sampled = readFrame(V);
    end
    i = i + 1;
end
```

This method is terribly slow. It seems that a marginally faster method, but less precise for many video processing purposes, is to

2) Sample based on time instead of frame

The `readFrame` documentation shows how a user can set a start time using `V.CurrentTime = x`. I imagine this lends itself to a sampling loop like

```
t = 0
V = VideoReader(filename);
while hasFrame(V)
    V.CurrentTime = t;
    sampled = readFrame(V);
    t = t + samplingPeriod;
end
```

This approach is still extremely slow as well.

This change seems to have either obfuscated the sampling process or dramatically slowed it down. Is there an explanation for this change? Am I missing some different, third method of sampling video that may be faster?

Comment: @horchler: It's a similar question, but I don't know if I'd call it a duplicate. I already know about `read()`. I guess the answer thus is that there is no better method?

Comment: Unless you want to try using the deprecated `read` function (see code in the my answer to the possible duplicate), there's no way around the slowness of using `readFrame` that I know of. No idea why this change was made. I suggest that you [file a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs) to ask about it and say why this functionality is important to you.

Comment: "I guess the answer thus is that there is no better method?" Yep, which is why I marked it duplicate.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I think it's worth leaving on the site as well as it addresses the sampling problem more in depth than the original question, but I voted to close as well

Comment: @marcman that is odd, authors should have a binding close vote for duplicates on their own post.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: You mean that when I voted to close, it should have done it regardless of the other votes? I agree that makes sense. Bring it up in meta

Comment: I was told in the mean time that the binding self-vote only applies if the post was not edited after the first duplicate close vote. I'm not saying it's best this way, but it's probably by design:) We could bring up a feature request to let OP have a binding duplicate vote under all circumstances (above the necessary reputation for this), but I'm not sure it's worth the effort.